# EventEmitter.prototype in reactjs, this.on is not working and says it's not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, eventemitter

```
this.on('change', callback);
```

and

```
this.removeListener('change', callback);
```

are not working on my `addChangeListener` and `removeChangeListener`. I've imported the `EventEmitter` and used it with object-assign (`"object-assign": "^4.1.1"`).

But it produces an error:

> bundle.js:41229 Uncaught TypeError: this.on is not a function
>           at Object.addChangeListener (bundle.js:41229)
>           at Authors.componentWillMount (bundle.js:40504)
>           at callComponentWillMount (bundle.js:26260)
>           at mountClassInstance (bundle.js:26356)
>           at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:27725)
>           at beginWork (bundle.js:28366)
>           at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:31198)
>           at workLoop (bundle.js:31227)
>           at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:19504)
>           at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:19542)

Here's my code:

```js
"use strict";

import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher';
import ActionTypes from '../constants/actionTypes';
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
import assign from 'object-assign';
import _ from 'lodash';

var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';
var _author = [];

var AuthorStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.protoType, {
  addChangeListener(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },
  removeChangeListener(callback) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },
  emitChange() {
    this.emit;
  },
  getAllAuthors() {
    return _author;
  },
  getAuthorById(id) {
    return _.find(_author, {
      id: id
    });
  }
});

AppDispatcher.register(function(action) {
  switch (action.actionType) {
    case ActionTypes.INITIALIZE:
      _author = action.initialData.authors;
      AuthorStore.emitChange();
      break;
    case ActionTypes.UPDATE_AUTHOR:
      var existingAuthor = _.find(_author, {
        id: action.author.id
      });
      var existingAuthorIndex = _.indexOf(_author, existingAuthor);
      _author.splice(existingAuthorIndex, 1, action.author);
      AuthorStore.emitChange();
      break;
    case ActionTypes.CREATE_AUTHOR:
      _author.push(action.author);
      AuthorStore.emitChange();
      break;
    case ActionTypes.DELETE_AUTHOR:
      _.remove(_author, function(author) {
        return action.id === author.id;
      });
      AuthorStore.emitChange();
      break;
    default:

  }
});

export default AuthorStore;
```

I can't figure out why it's not working, I've been referring on this [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter).
Thank You.

Comment: try console.log(this.on) and see what it is and whether its available

Comment: it returns **undefined**... @fatahn

Comment: what does `this` refer to when you console.log(this) just below `var AuthorStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.protoType, {
`?

Comment: `{addChangeListener: ƒ, removeChangeListener: ƒ, emitChange: ƒ, getAllAuthors: ƒ, getAuthorById: ƒ}
addChangeListener
:
ƒ addChangeListener(callback)
emitChange
:
ƒ emitChange()
getAllAuthors
:
ƒ getAllAuthors()
getAuthorById
:
ƒ getAuthorById(id)
removeChangeListener
:
ƒ removeChangeListener(callback)
__proto__
:
Object ` it can't be done after `var AuthorStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.protoType, {` it returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by changing all items into named object properties like this:

```
// BEFORE
addChangeListener(callback) {
// AFTER
addChangeListener: function (callback) {

// BEFORE
removeChangeListener(callback) {
// AFTER
removeChangeListener: function (callback) {
```

...and so on.